# how to save and restore an object into a file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, object

I have a class like this:

```
classdef my_class
properties
    prop_a
    prop_b
end

methods(Static)
    ...
    function o = load()
       ??? 
    end

end

methods
    function save(o)
       ??? 
    end
    ...
end end
```

Please help me to write save and load methods.
name of methods is clear and they should save and restore an object from a text file...

the properties are quite dynamic and have different row/col number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [save function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), you can save variables to file. As documented in the [load function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html), you can load variables from file.

```
methods(Static)
    function obj = loadFromFile( filename )
        obj = load( filename );
    end
end

methods
    function saveToFile( obj, filename )
        save( 'test', 'obj' );
    end
end
```

Caveat

- Note that you need to specify the full path for the filenames or the object will be saved/loaded to/from the working directory.